# Strange encoding of ldap_explode_dn results

Tags: php, encoding, ldap

After converting DN string with `ldap_explode_dn` some characters (cyrillic in my case) are converted to other encoding that I can't recognize.

For example `ldap_explode_dn('cn=tt,ou=groups,o=ц1,ou=realms,dc=uvf,dc=local', 0);` return

```
Array
(
    [0] => tt
    [1] => groups
    [2] => \D1\861
    [3] => realms
    [4] => uvf
    [5] => local
)
```

As you can see, `ц` character was converted to `\D1\86`. I guess it is two-byte UTF-8, but I can't get how I can decode it.

I have tried many ways like `iconv` and `mb_convert_encoding`, but without success.

**My question is** - what is this encoding and how to work with it in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this user note on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-explode-dn.php#34724) which provides a solution for your problem.

---

**EDIT:**
The modifier *e* is deprecated for preg_replace since PHP 5.5 so here is a solution with preg_replace_callback instead based on the linked user note:

```
function myldap_explode_dn( $dn, $with_attrib ) {
    $result = ldap_explode_dn( $dn, $with_attrib );

    //translate hex code into ascii again
    foreach ( $result as $key => $value ) {
        $result[ $key ] = preg_replace_callback(
            "/\\\([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/",
            function ( $matches) {
                return chr( hexdec( $matches[1] ) );
            },
            $value
        );
    }

    return ( $result );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I saw this solution, but I think it's workaround. I'll wait for other answers for a day and accept your answer if there is no better solution (I doubt there is any actually).